# Calling/Executing Contracts from low level languages for standalone program

Tags: contract-development, dapp-development, json-rpc

Is there any way to call a contract from lower level languages (c, c++, rust, etc), say for some standalone executable/program?

Basically do all interfaces with the ethereum network have to be through the browser or Mist client?

If not does anyone have any examples/resources.

Answer (score 1):

Using [JSON-RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) you can [sendTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendtransaction) and invoke a contract from any language.